# Can a gen3 SATA harddrive be forced to always link at gen2 speed?

Tags: windows, sata

Is there a PC tool to program a gen3 SATA harddrive to avoid a link attempt at the gen3 speed (6Gb) and always start the link negotiation at the gen2 speed (3Gb)?

Comment: Why? The link will be made at Gen2 speeds automatically if one of the endpoints doesn't support it, and if both endpoints support Gen3, why not use it?

Comment: @tfont - What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: Wikipeida explains this topic quite extensively here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Backward_and_forward_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Some newer SATA drives will have a jumper block that allows you to force them to a certain link speed. You would have to check the drive manufactures site for the specific details on your model. Not really a PC tool, but it does what you're looking to do.

[image: SATA Jumper Block]